# select the first time three unique values appear with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

From the table below as an example, I need to select all fields from a table where the first 3 columns are the exact same, and take the first time this instance appears. For example, rows 1,3 and 4 should be selected, as they have differing values in the first 3 columns. I have been given this data, and there is no unique ID. There are about 25000 records so handling this once I have SELECT the data in python seems silly therefore the only methods I can think are deleting the records that are nearly identical, or using a SELECT statement I have not worked out yet. Would it be better do try and select the data in small amounts and use python to use the correct bits, as while this is messier, I know how to do it this way?

```
ID | Class | Season | Grade
---|-------|--------|---------
 1 |   x   |    1   |   A
 1 |   x   |    1   |   A*
 1 |   y   |    1   |   A
 1 |   x   |    2   |   C
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need to select every field though, the distinct works nicely with those three fields, but how can I select all fields?

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields. And _rows_, not records.

Comment: I am using mySQL sorry

Comment: Are you housekeeping the table? would you like to update the table by removing the duplicates?

Comment: How do you define the *first* appearance? We need another column to order the records.

Comment: Is it possible to have different grade for rows with duplicate id, class, season?

Comment: @Mattattack . . . To reiterate GMB's comment:  There is no "first" (or "third") occurrence of anything in a table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering.

Comment: @SalmanA the grades will most likely be different, hence the easiest way to spot a 'duplicate' piece of data is from the first 3 columns as they will always be the same.

Comment: @GMB There is no way to tell the difference between each record, I suppose by 'first' I mean the first time it appears when mysql selects it, it doesn't actually matter what is selects first; it can be random.

Comment: @tcadidot0 I would rather not because there may be use for the records being in this table. Also, to delete the correct amount of records from the 25k, I would need the same SQL statement that I am already looking for to select them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DISTINCT *` it means "select all columns and skip any rows where the values in all columns match some already included row".

So with `LIMIT 3` you will have the first 3 unique rows:

```
SELECT distinct * FROM yourTable LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Does MySQL really support `top 3`?

Comment: You're right, but it should support Limit, with LIMIT 3 we should get a similar result, right?

Comment: Same result, but perhaps not what OP wants. (It's not very clear what the problem is.)

Comment: Sorry @jarlh the data I have been provided makes it very hard to detail the problem at hand. LIMIT 3 only returns the first three records. For every item in my table, they will have about 8 records that inner join the record in this table. So for each item, they will have 2 records for each 'season' one representing their own entry for the 'grade' and the other is a superiors representation of their 'grade'. Therefore the ID, Class and season are all the same, but there is no way to tell which record is the self / superior evaluation. I basically need just one of these two records.

Answer (score 0):

You want the first three unique rows.  You can actually do this pretty easily if you have an ordering column:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, class, season order by <orderingcol>) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by <orderingcol>
limit 3;
```

Actually, the subquery is not necessary, but the query is a bit more inscrutable without it:

```
select t.*
from t
where seqnum = 1
order by row_number() over (partition by id, class, season order by <orderingcol>),
          <orderingcol>
limit 3;
```

The one caveat is that this will return duplicates if there are not three unique ones.

Window functions were introduced in MySQL 8+.  This could be phrased in earlier versions of MySQL as well:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select id, class, season,  min(<ordering col>) as min_oc
      from t
     ) tt
     using (id, class, season)
where t.<ordering col> = tt.min_oc
order by tt.min_oc;
```

Comment: Sorry for the poor clarity, I need a lot more than 3 rows. There are 4 seasons, and for each season an item will have two or three records in this table that refer to it by 'id', meaning that id, season and class are all duplicated, and I need only one of these two of the records, for every id for every season. So I need to select about 12500 records from the 25000.

Comment: @Mattattack . . . You can remove the `limit` then.

Comment: Both methods seem to throw an error near the 'partition by' statement, not sure what I am doing wrong.. is there anything in particular I should I should not order by?

Comment: If you have error on `partition by` it simply means that you're using a MySQL version that doesn't support it. As Gordon mention in his edit, this function only introduced in MySQL 8+. Perhaps the last suggestion he gave is working for you @Mattattack ?

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff what is meant by min_oc, and how is it used?