# Alter table to add unique ID on multiple columns, ignoring duplicates

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I believe this line of code will help me create a unique id  based on three columns, while ignoring any time the combination of these three columns is duplicated, yet ignore seems depreciated with mysql and I can not find another way to do this?

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `x` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `id`('student', 'class', 'session');
```

Comment: This behaviour was removed in 5.7.4 (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456520/mysql-alter-ignore-table-add-unique-what-will-be-truncated))

Comment: @Nick that seems to explain how ignore works, not an alternative method?

Comment: There isn't an alternate any more, you need to remove duplicates before you can create a unique key. In the older versions of MySQL it would do that for you when you used an `ALTER IGNORE` command.

Comment: Is there a way I can use an old mysql version to perform this statement?

Comment: You just need to emulate the action of the old statement by removing all the duplicates manually. There are *many* answers on stackoverflow that tell how to do that.

Comment: Please can you link me to one of these answers? I have been searching around for two weeks and am yet to find one that has worked well (hence why I have asked a question), I have around 30000 records and I am very unfamiliar with mysql.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: @Nick the problem I had with this, is that none of the rows are identical, however, in a case where three of the columns are the same as another row, then I would need to delete one of these. I finally thought I had found a solution with IGNORE. I have tried expressing this problem with another question, but I am still very stuck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58500201/select-the-first-time-three-unique-values-appear-with-sql/58503639#58503639